# CSS - Change animation-play-state of Element A from Element B and dynamic selectors using variables?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, css-selectors, css-animations

Imagine I want to change Element A's **animation-play-state** property value from **Element B** inside a keyframe referencing the element that has an animation with the same name but for example I want **Element B** to be paused and **A** running and when the **A** animation finishes then point the next Element with an animation with the same name, which is **Element B**, and run the animation while ending the one in **Element A**.

Something like:

```
.element1 {
  animation: anim 2s infinite 3s alternate both;
}
.element {
  animation: anim 2s infinite 3s alternate pause both;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {
    this-element{ animation-play-state: pause;}
    next-element{ animation-play-state: running;}
  }
}
```

Is there something like this in pure *CSS*?
Also, it is not possible to create selectors to different elements dinamically using counters or varialbes like having multiple  tags and assigning a class with numbers like

```
<img class="im1" src="" />
<img class="im2" src="" />
```

And then doing

```
:root {--imnumber: 0}
div > img:before {--imnumber: calc(--imnumber + 1)}
.im--imnumber {
  some-properties: value;
}
```

Isn't there something like this in pure *CSS* using no *SASS* or *SCSS* etc?
I think *CSS* by its own would be a lot better by allowing these things without the need of 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this from what I understand of your explanation. Seems like you're trying to animate one element after another in series? If you don't want to use JS to detect when an animation completes you can just add a delay to each element's animation so it won't start animating until the previous one has completed. I'm a little confused why you have all your animations set to infinite if you want them to stop when the next animation starts.

Comment: That is a mistake of mine since I haven't played too much with animations and I am experimenting and practicing things.
So yes, it looks like the iterations count should be at 1, and like you said I wan't to play the animation in series but to be restarting all over from the first element.